# Backup-Spsite always failing with HRESULT 0x80131904

Tags: powershell, backup

While taking backup of Site Collection on SharePoint 2010 using powershell command `"Backup-SPSite"` I always encounter below error :

> "Backup-SPSite : Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 At line:1 char:14
>   + Backup-SPSite <<<< -Identity http://< -Path <> + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...mdletBackupSite: SPCmdletBackupSite)
>   [Backup-SPSite], SPException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletBackupSite"

I have a farm with 2 WFE, 1 App Server, 1 DB Server. I am farm administrator and performing backup on my appServer using PowerShell (Backup-spsite). I have all the rights as administrator on all the machines / drives / databases.

Well, site collection is more then 7GB in size. The Backup-spsite command runs for few mins and the resulting .bak file reaches 4.64 GB. I noticed that exactly at this size, it gets the exception mentioned above.

Below is the error which I saw in ULS viewer:

> Error Category: InvalidData Target Object
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletBackupSite Details NULL
>   RecommendedAction NULL

Comment: I swear I've seen this behavior before, but can't recall the solution. The fact that it always fails on the exact size rings a bell.

Comment: Its ok Cameron. Kindly let me know the solution once you recall it back. I am struggling since June 2013. This is in production server of one of my client.

Comment: since *June 2013* xD

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if there is a enough free space in the location you are saving the .bak file **as well as** the directory where temp files are saved ?

It first writes it to the temp dir and than moves it to your location, effectively you need the target .BAK size as free space twice.

EDIT:

According to [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9bd5e7de-9fa5-4e44-b5fc-91b51ced78a7/backupspsite-always-failing-with-hresult-0x80131904?forum=sharepointadminprevious) a bit down the thread, his issue was caused because the admin account running the powershell script did not have sufficient permissions to the destination folder. He also saw the error you had at a fixed size point in the .bak file.

Comment: Thanks Cameron  for your quick reply. Free space is more than 21 GB. Still I am encountering the same problem. I am facing this issue for this site collection since June 2013. Still not able to resolve.

However I am able to backup other site collection in different web application but on same server successfully. The size is around 800 MB

Comment: I have given full permissions to the account on destination folder.
If permission would have been the problem then it should not allow me to backup even a single MB, whereas the backup file goes till 4GB and then stucks.
Also I am able to backup other site collection successfully to the same destination folder.

Comment: What's different between the 2 site collections ? Have you checked uls logs to see if any other errors occur that might be related ?

Comment: @Amin How much free space do you have on the C drive and D drive. I assume you are backing up to the D drive, then you need at least 5GB on both.

Comment: @Amin Do you were able to solve this issue? I have exactly the same issue. It starts to backup, then after a while it breaks. The time, when it breaks differs.